# Use a TeXStudio usercommand for executing .bat in project directory

Tags: texstudio, windows

I would like to create a usercommand in TeXStudio 2.11.0 which executes a batch-file in the same directory like the .tex-file. Is it possible to do it dynamically? Currently I'm only able to set the whole path to the batch-file.

Background: I want to execute the make "makeindex"-command for creating the necessary files for my acronyms. And I'm currently working on multiple .tex-files so the direct path is really annoying.

My current system: Windows 10 and TeXStudio 2.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *Special Chars* syntax construct the path dynamically. For your case, that would be: (need Advanced Options enabled to see the complete s

`?a)\test.bat`

See `Options -> Commands -> Special Chars` for an explanation. To see the full list, you have to enable Advanced Options:

[image]

Comment: thank you! here is my solution with your help @Tim Hoffmann:
the makeglossaries command: `?a)acronyms.bat`
the create and display command: `txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///compile | txs:///view`